# Write The name with ssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a SSL certificate.

In this picture: there is green block inscribed PayPal.

I have a SSL certificate installed on the storage cPanel and I want to do the same

How do I do that?

Comment: Its not quite clear what you are asking. Can you try and describe it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that is the Green Bar that you are talking about. That is supported by many browsers such as Chrome and I believe you would require an EV certificate for that and that does cost some money.

These requirements are in a state of flux and most recently there is this as well:

https://blog.digicert.com/certificate-transparency-required-ev-certificates-show-green-address-bar-chrome/

So in short, get an EV certificate and make sure that it works on the browsers that are in your support matrix.